# Javascript Popup Over a Flash Piece

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have a flash piece and I'm trying to use an absolutely positioned element overtop of the flash piece when a div is clicked.   In Chrome and IE 11, the div shows correctly overtop of the flash piece.  But on Firefox and Safari the popup does not show up overtop of the flash piece even if I add a z-index to the popup.

Link to code:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/tyd3jcfqy64dm3x/stackOverflow-Flash.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the wmode attribute to the embed object and set it to "transparent".

See how here: http://www.thecave.info/overlay-html-over-flash-object